# Bookshelfjs: How to fetch all entries based on information of another table

Tags: mysql, bookshelf.js

I have a table of `users` and `courses` (ex: psychology 101, poli sci 205, etc.). I also have a join table called `users_courses`. I want to fetch all the courses that belong to a user.

I have two questions pertaining to solving this problem:

1. Should I be using `fetchAll()` on a model or a collection (`course` vs `courses`). What is the difference?
2. In bookshelf, how do I reference all the courses that belong to a particular user?

Answer (score 1):

1. `fetchAll()` is a model function (see [fetchAll](http://bookshelfjs.org/#Model-instance-fetchAll)). It brings a collection of models based on query parameters firing `'fetching'` and `'fetched'` events as they happen.
2. in contrast `fetch()` brings only the current model (or a model matching currently set attributes), like:

   ```
   new User({name: 'Mary Jane'})
     .fetch({withRelated: 'courses'})
     .then(function(mary) {
        console.log('Mary Jane and her courses: ' + mary.toJSON());
     });
   ```

For this example I assume your models are:

```
var User = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'users',
  courses: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany('Course', 'users_courses');
  }
});
bookshelf.model('User', User);

var Course = bookshelf.Model.extend({
  tableName: 'courses',
  users: function() {
    return this.belongsToMany('User', 'users_courses');
  }
});
bookshelf.model('Course', Course);
```